# Does std::vector have a { Initial number of elements} constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

In [cplusplus reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), Perhabs
there is not { initial number of elements } constructor.
The example is like below.

```
vector<string> svec { 5 }; 
cout << svec.capacity() << endl; // log is 5
```

But, there is `explicit vector (size_type n);` constructor. In this case, this is not `{ }` brace. What happened to this statement ?

Comment: Use the [better reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) please.

Comment: In your link it shows that there is a constructor which can be called with one integer argument. What the problem?

Comment: I read the guide somewhere, `{ }` is  initializer list. But in `vector<string> svec { 5 }; ` case, this is not initializer list becuse `value type` is `string`. So, Where is the constructor with one integer argument ? There is `(one integer argument) meaning size type` only. It is `( ) brace`, not `{ }`

Comment: _"Perhabs there is not { initial number of elements } constructor."_ Yes there is. It's #2.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is it same between `{} and ()` constructor ?

Comment: @fasdgoc You seem to misunderstand something about initializer lists and have some unjustified assumptions.

Comment: I thought `{ }` is used for initializer list. `()` is used for constructor like function

Comment: I will find this concept. thank you.

Comment: @fasdgoc: Unfortunately that's an over-simplification. `{}` is _uniform initialisation syntax_. It can be used with an initialiser list, or with normal constructors. That also means you cannot initialise a vector with one element using `{}` without further trickery, because the constructor "comes first".

Comment: @Steve: That's not true, as the OP's example shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, there is explicit vector (size_type n); constructor. In this case, this is not { } brace. What happened to this statement ?

Uniform initialisation syntax means that, mostly, these two are the same:

```
SomeType objectName(constructor_args);
SomeType objectName{constructor_args};
```

Curly braces may also be used under some circumstances to populate an *initialiser list*, but that's not the case here.

You are indeed invoking the second constructor, the one that specifies the number of elements the vector should start with.

C++ initialisation is quite complex, so I shan't go into more detail here but prod you into doing some related reading on all the various initialisation syntaxes. Your C++ book should cover them.